# Cannot run katalon.exe

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

When I click on katalon.exe, it runs into the problem: "An error has occurred. See the log file C:...\configuration\1632037666424.log"

And when I click the log file, it appears as below:

```
katalon.versionNumber=8.1.0
katalon.buildNumber=208
!SESSION 2021-09-19 14:47:45.953 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_282
java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-09-19 14:47:48.348
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The platform metadata area could not be written: C:\Program Files (x86)\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-8.1.0\config\.metadata.  By default the platform writes its content
under the current working directory when the platform is launched.  Use the -data parameter to
specify a different content area for the platform.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.getBaseLocation(InstancePreferences.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.initializeChildren(InstancePreferences.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.<init>(InstancePreferences.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.internalCreate(InstancePreferences.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.createNode(PreferencesService.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getChild(RootPreferences.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.InstanceScope.getNode(InstanceScope.java:80)
    at com.kms.katalon.preferences.internal.ScopedPreferenceStore.getStorePreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:216)
    at com.kms.katalon.preferences.internal.ScopedPreferenceStore.<init>(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:117)
    at com.kms.katalon.preferences.internal.PreferenceStoreManager.initialPreferenceStore(PreferenceStoreManager.java:25)
    at com.kms.katalon.preferences.internal.PreferenceStoreManager.getPreferenceStore(PreferenceStoreManager.java:21)
    at com.kms.katalon.application.preference.ProxyPreferences.getPreferenceStore(ProxyPreferences.java:134)
    at com.kms.katalon.application.preference.ProxyPreferences.isSystemProxyPreferencesSet(ProxyPreferences.java:91)
    at com.kms.katalon.application.preference.ProxyPreferences.getSystemProxyInformation(ProxyPreferences.java:96)
    at com.kms.katalon.application.Application.runGUI(Application.java:190)
    at com.kms.katalon.application.Application.start(Application.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

And this is how my katalon.ini looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552
-data
@noDefault
-vmargs
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Xms256m
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
-Xmx2048m
```

It seems like I have to change the @noDefault but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me :<

Comment: Are you running Katalon as Admin?

Comment: It worked! Can you explain more on how I run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Katalon as administrator.

To do that automatically in Windows, right-click the Katalon shortcut and in Properties > Advanced select the "Run as administrator" checkbox.